# How do I text-align:center php echo text in Firefox?

Tags: php, firefox, safari, css, echo

I don't see this question answered anywhere else here.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="copyright">
<h2 class="copyright unselectable" onselectstart="return false">
&copy;&nbsp;2009&nbsp;-&nbsp;<?=date("Y") ?>&nbsp;<?=PROJECT_NAME?>
</h2>
</div>
```

It's aligning right in IE but not FF or Safari.  It seems to not be taking into account the spacing for the echoed text?

Thanks!

Edit:  Adding css that is there:

```
div.copyright h2.copyright{
  font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:13px;
  color:#000000;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Second Edit:
Well I just hard coded the text with the same results...so it's not the echo issue like I though.  I'll have to look deeper at this.

Comment: what does your css look like? also why are u using `&nbsp;`?

Comment: Screenshots would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry-I thought the css would be self-explanatory 
h2.copyright{
  font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:13px;
  color:#000000;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
} 

I guess I can make a screenshot-but basically in FF and Safari, the text is moved over about 4 characters too far to the left.  

I tried nbsp; to see if it made a difference-it doesn't

Comment: What is the actual HTML the browser sees?

Comment: <div class="copyright"><h2 class="copyright unselectable" onselectstart="return false">&copy;&nbsp;2009&nbsp;-&nbsp;2010&nbsp;Monkey Mind Manager (beta 1.1)</h2>

</div>

Comment: What's the CSS code for the "unselectable" property? Maybe it overwrites the CSS rules for h2.copyright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  I fixed it-and the answer is too stupid to post here...

...haha  The box above the copyright area was not centering right in ff and safari but was right in IE. :-D

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `style` attribute to `H2`:

```
<h2 class="copyright unselectable" onselectstart="return false" style="text-align:center">
&copy;&nbsp;2009&nbsp;-&nbsp;<?=date("Y") ?>&nbsp;<?=PROJECT_NAME?>
</h2>
```

Or better, add that property to your CSS rule for `.copyright`:

```
.copyright {
    text-align: center;
    /* … */
}
```

Comment: hi-sorry for the confusion.  That is already in the CSS.  For some reason the echo text seems to not be taken into consideration

Answer (score 0):

The code sample that you posted seems to be aligning correctly to the center in both Firefox and Safari (on a Mac). The correct CSS to use is `text-align: center;`. What is the HTML and the associated CSS surrounding that piece of code? There could be something else causing the text to not look centered.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
div.copyright h2.copyright{
  font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:13px;
  color:#000000;
  margin:0 auto;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the h2 a width. If you're using a reset stylesheet it's default styling may have been over ridden. If the h2 isn't wider than it's text, then it will appear that the text isn't being centered.